# What is the Java equivalent of Python's subprocess.Popen()?

Tags: java, python, subprocess

```
import subprocess
import os

prefix = os.path.expanduser("~/.bin/kb/")
p = subprocess.Popen([(prefix + "koreball"),(prefix + "/data"),'3'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Your can try with the `Runtime.exec` method.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("myprocess");
```

The method returns a `Process` that can be used to:

- Retrieve the process output, input and error streams
- Retrieve the process output code
- Kill the process
- Wait for the end of the process execution

Comment: Does the python version suffer the same memory issues that the java one does due to os fork?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're asking, but if you're looking for the Java equivalent of `Popen()`, you want [`Runtime.exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 1):

Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) e.g.

```
static void SimpleProcess() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", ".")
            .inheritIO();

    Process p = pb.start();

    int retval = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("exited with code "  + retval);
}
```