# function that creates custom variables in java

Tags: java, string, eval

In Python it's quite easy:

```py
def function(variable_name,variable_value):
    exec(str(variable_name) + "=" + str(variable_value))
```

`exec()` converts string into code to run; in this case it creates a variable. I'm looking for something like this in Java:

```
static void method (String variable_name; String variable_value){
     exec_eval_in_java("String " + variable_name + " = " + variable_value + ";");
}
```

Comment: Java does not have an eval. There is no equivalent in Java. The closest would be a byte code generating utility, like [asm](https://asm.ow2.io/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how can i use it? im a beginner

Comment: 100% not for beginners. Hence the start of the comment: "Java does not have an eval. There is no equivalent in Java."

Comment: Bad idea in Python and an even worse idea in Java. Whatever you actually need to do, this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it Dynamically if you compile and load a java class:

```
String className = "package.myClass";
String code = "package package;\n" + 
    "public class myClass{}\n"
```

and so on you can write your code like that and then:

```
Class class = CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER.loadFromJava(className, code);
Runnable runnable= (Runnable) class.newInstance();
runnable.run();
```

You can have a look into:
[How do you dynamically compile and load external java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes) and [Is there an equivalent to Python's exec() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973921/is-there-an-equivalent-to-pythons-exec-function-in-java)

You can also check the git hub [Java-Runtime-Compiler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler)

Comment: Can you give a hint/link to the library providing `CompilerUtils`?